# Map numpy array using dict?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a potentially long array of one's and zero's that looks like this:
`a = [0,0,1,0,1,0,.....]`
I want to translate each consecutive pair of values to an integer between 0 & 3 as shown below:

- 0,0 -> 0
- 0,1 -> 1
- 1,0 -> 3
- 1,1 -> 2

I'm looking for a nice clean efficient way to create the array b (example output below) using the mapping above:
`b = [0, 3, 3,...]`

Is a dict a good idea? I can't figure out how to do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
x = np.reshape(a, (-1,2))

b = x[:,0]*2 + (x[:,0] ^ x[:,1])
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the way to use a function. I was thinking I'd have to create a map.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the successive pairs as **indices to perform a look-up**, for getting the translated value:

```
master = np.array([[0, 1],[3, 2]])
b = master[a[::2], a[1::2]]
```

**Test input:**

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: The mapping given in the question would be standard for [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code). There's no reason to assume it's a typo.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica -- Thanks for pointing out. I've now modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a dict with an explicit mapping between corresponding decimal numbers, you could try this:

```
# Convert to a (-1,2) matrix and decimal numbers first
a = np.reshape(a, (-1,2))
a = np.sum(np.array([2,1])*a, axis=1)

# Define dictionary with mapping
D = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2}

# Apply dictionary
a = [D[x] for x in a]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the reshape idea but kept trying to figure out how to use a 2 element array as the key in a dict.